# Spell checking in Word automatically turns off

Tags: microsoft-word, input-languages

I use Office word 2016, I installed two languages Persian and English. In an English document I turn on spelling checking via Review > Languages via the shown dialog box. I uncheck the "Do not check the spelling errors"

[image]

But it just works for one or two words, and surprisingly, it again turns off automatically after I write some sentences. As I check the dialog box again the tick mark is there! I don't know if it is a virus or a bug or I do something wrong.

I should say "check spelling as you type" option in File > Options > Proofing is also ticked!

Answer (score 0):

As the box says (first line of text), it applies only to the *selected text*. Even if you select *all* text in the document, it applies to this *existing* text, not to any future one you write.

If you want it to apply to new (or *any* text), you should change the style you use accordingly. For example, to change the style 'Normal', right click it, chose 'Modify', and then in the bottom left, open the 'format' drop down, and find the setting for 'Language'. It looks the same, but this is the standard setting for all text (in that style).

Comment: I did your suggestion for `body text` which is the style of my text, but there the option is already unchecked!